# Memory problems when creating a large PHP array for leaflet

Tags: php, json, geospatial, geojson

I have a MySQL 8 spatial database with about 450 entries. Unfortunately I can't use PostGre/PostGIS at my webspace, what I'm more familiar with. For local testing I use Xampp with php to load the data in leaflet map.

I got the error message:

> Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 135168 bytes) in C:\xampp\htdocs\xgis\php\test3.php on line 21

This points to `'geometry' => json_decode($row['geo'])`

The whole data length of all 450 records is about 11MB

The largest record has 85.000 characters as json (mainly the SHAPE entry). If i reduce precession from ST_AsGeoJSON(SHAPE,5) to 4 I got 78.500 characters. If I save it to notepadd is about 80 KB

If I use local: `ini_set('memory_limit', '1024M');` I got the expected result. But I wan't use this online. So I tried to buffer the result with `MYSQLI_USE_RESULT` but I got the error message. I've read some posts and the php doc about the issue but I didn't find a solution.

```
<?php
    //ini_set('memory_limit', '1024M');
    // mysqli_set_charset($conn,'utf8');
    $sql = "SELECT *, ST_AsGeoJSON(SHAPE,5) as geo FROM gem_grenzen;";

    $geojson = array(
       'type'      => 'FeatureCollection',
       'features'  => array()
    );


    $result = $conn->query($sql, MYSQLI_USE_RESULT);

        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $properties = $row;
            unset($properties['geo']);
            unset($properties['SHAPE']);

            $feature = array(
                 'type' => 'Feature',
                 'geometry' => json_decode($row['geo']), 
                 'properties' => $properties 
            );
            array_push($geojson['features'], $feature);

        }

    echo 'var $foo =';
    echo json_encode($geojson, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
    echo "; \r\n";
    echo 'L.geoJSON($foo,{style:style_gem}).addTo(map);';
    ?>
```

Comment: What error you got?

Comment: why did you omit the most vital part of the error message? The pointer to the actual line where error happened? Does it point at json_encode? If so, how it's related to mysqli?

Comment: > Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 135168 bytes) in C:\xampp\htdocs\xgis\php\test3.php on line 21

This points to `'geometry' => json_decode($row['geo'])`

Comment: Thank you. It seems that it's the amount of data you've got, not mysqli to blame. What's the size of one record?  And do you really need to return all that multi-megabyte json? Are you sure you need to return *whole* seems-to-be-leviathan 'geometry' array? May be the amount of data returned can be reduced?

Comment: The largest record has 85.000 characters as json (mainly the SHAPE entry). If i reduce precession from `ST_AsGeoJSON(SHAPE,5)` to 4 I got 78.500 characters. If I save it to noteapd it's about 80 KB. Didn't thought this would be a problem. But just to be sure, would the line of code `$result = $conn->query($sql, MYSQLI_USE_RESULT);` be correct or/and is there another way to pass the geojson like zip. Speed ​​is not really a requirement.

Comment: The whole data length of the 450 records is about 11MB

Comment: So it takes PHP a lot more to store it in the memory. Anyway, are you already using an unbuffered query hence your problem lies elsewhere

Answer (score 0):

I've debugged/traced my script with Xdebug https://xdebug.org with the settings `xdebug.auto_trace` and `xdebug.show_mem_delta`. As a result the memory problem is caused by `array_push($geojson['features'], $feature);`

```
0.4779  130073936   -44160         -> json_decode() C:\xampp\htdocs\xgis\php\test3.php:22
0.4783  130459928  +385992         -> array_push() C:\xampp\htdocs\xgis\php\test3.php:25
0.4784  130459928       +0         -> mysqli_result->fetch_assoc() C:\xampp\htdocs\xgis\php\test3.php:14
0.4785  130542744   +82816         -> json_decode() C:\xampp\htdocs\xgis\php\test3.php:22
0.4798  131909512 +1366768         -> array_push() C:\xampp\htdocs\xgis\php\test3.php:25
0.4799  131909512       +0         -> mysqli_result->fetch_assoc() C:\xampp\htdocs\xgis\php\test3.php:14
0.4799  131853048   -56464         -> json_decode() C:\xampp\htdocs\xgis\php\test3.php:22
0.4806  132541400  +688352         -> array_push() C:\xampp\htdocs\xgis\php\test3.php:25
0.4806  132541400       +0         -> mysqli_result->fetch_assoc() C:\xampp\htdocs\xgis\php\test3.php:14
```

So I have to rewrite the code with a [leaflet featuregroup](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.6.0.html#featuregroup) and add every record as an own variable instead of one large array.

Comment: Did you try to use $geojson['features'][] = $feature instead of array push?

Comment: `$geojson['features'][] = $feature` not really change something. I can load about 10 records more.     `0.5694  144214376     +896         -> json_decode() C:\xampp\htdocs\xgis\php\test3.php:23
    0.5701  144726760  +512384         -> mysqli_result->fetch_assoc() C:\xampp\htdocs\xgis\php\test3.php:15
    0.5701  144719448    -7312         -> json_decode() C:\xampp\htdocs\xgis\php\test3.php:23
    0.5706  145130256  +410808         -> mysqli_result->fetch_assoc() C:\xampp\htdocs\xgis\php\test3.php:15`